# Drag UICollectionView footer to new collection

Tags: xcode, uicollectionview, interface-builder

I am trying to drag a footer view from one UICollectionView to another, and every time it decides the view is the header instead, the only place it will allow me to drop the view is at the top.  Even when I have a header, it just replaces.

Is there a way to change the header to the footer or drop this as the footer in Xcode?

Answer (score 0):

A friend at work showed me that you can copy paste instead of dragging, it did the trick.  You do have to paste over the auto created footer.